# Maven project throws ClassNotFoundException in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc

When running my spring boot application with maven dependencies in eclipse I get the following exception at startup:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/context/support/GenericWebApplicationContext
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createApplicationContext(SpringApplication.java:574) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:325) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at co.hafiz.cm.launcher.Launcher.lambda$0(Launcher.java:33) [classes/:na]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
... 32 common frames omitted
```

While in maven dependencies in eclipse I got:
[image]

as you can see `spring-web` is available which contains 
`org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext`
what would be the problem?

Comment: GenericWebApplicationContext is in Spring Framework

Comment: Can we see your pom.xml ?

Comment: Maybe into eclipse try "Clean..." from the server contextual menu... can help

Comment: these are 2 different exceptions - the one in title and the actual error

Answer (score 2):

Adding dependency spring-boot-starter-web in my Spring Boot project resolved this same error. Also, you seem to have a lot of unnecessary dependencies in regard of Spring Boot. Some may be required in case of Spring framework but not in Spring Boot.

Answer (score 1):

you're missing spring framework, add it to your dependencies

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This dependency is not mandatory for running a Spring Boot application when spring-boot-starter-web is present. Also, it is clear in the image that he already has spring-core present.

Comment: @StutiVerma who said it is mandatory for starting Spring Boot application?

Comment: It is clearly visible that he already included spring-core because it is required to run a Spring application but similar is not the case in Spring Boot app.